# PasteSpecial Method of Range Run Error

Tags: vba, excel

```
Sub LoopOtherRevenue()

Dim MyFile As String
Dim FilePath As String
FilePath = "C:\Users\jdubbaneh002\Desktop\Racetrac Other\"
MyFile = Dir(FilePath)

Do While Len(MyFile) > 0
If MyFile = "Book1.xlsm" Then
Exit Sub
End If

ActiveSheet.Range("A1:B14").Copy

Workbooks.Open (FilePath & MyFile)
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("A2) Monthly P&L (Source)").Activate
Range("B746:C759").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
Application.CutCopyMode = False
ActiveWorkbook.Close

MyFile = Dir

Loop

End Sub
```

Get a paste special error on line Range("B746:C759").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
The values are being pasted into a combo box. that is where the error is coming from.

Comment: Define "won't run". Are you getting an error? Is it executing, but not doing what you expected it to do? What happens when you run it in the debugger (press F8 to execute each line of code).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me it seems like the file path is missing a "\"

```
FilePath = "C:\Users\jdubbaneh002\Desktop\Racetrac Other"
...
MyFile = Dir(FilePath)
...
If MyFile = "Book1.xlsm" Then
...
Workbooks.Open (FilePath & MyFile)
```

**Correct:**

```
Workbooks.Open (FilePath & "\" & MyFile)
```

Did you try debugging? Where does it throw the error?

Comment: Youre right I was missing a "\". It now runs, copies the selection, opens the other workbook and I now get "Pastspecial of range method class failed" Thanks for your help

Comment: Glad it helped. You need to however debug the code and mention which line is throwing the error. In my opinion opening the new Workbook before the copy should help. Please mark my post as answer.

Comment: New to this, believe I marked yours as an answer. Please see OP, I updated the code and error.

Answer (score 0):

I can see all sorts of issues because you're using `ActiveWorkbook` after opening the 2nd workbook. Is `ActiveWorkbook` still pointing at the one where the code is, or is it actually pointing at the one you just opened?

Create & set an `as Workbook` variable as assign the one the code is in to one, and the workbook you're opening to the other. That will eliminate all confusion.

Comment: Thanks for your help.I have updated my code, it runs now, copies the selction, attempts to paste it into destination workbook and i get a "Pastspecial of range method class failed" now.

Comment: try adding your new code to the bottom of your OP so we can see what you've done. (Don't remove the original, it may be of help to the next person who comes along with this issue.)

Comment: You're probably getting the error on `.PasteSpecial` because you don't have anything copied for it to paste, and you haven't specified what "special" thing you want it to paste. Google `excel vba .pastespecial` to get to the MS docs and it will tell you what you need to do.

Comment: I no longer have my original code, the most recent version is in my OP. Seems to have fixed a couple errors besides the pastespecial error now. Thanks for your help, for future guidance I will keep original code.

Comment: So the reason Im getting this error is because the area im trying to paste it into is a drop down box. I wrote the code with paste values syntax and tried it on  a blank sheet and it runs successfully.

Comment: That makes sense... :) If you need the values in your drop down, and if your drop down is based on a list, you could paste it into the list location instead.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Sub LoopOtherRevenue()
Dim rgCopy as Range
Dim MyFile As String
Dim FilePath As String
Dim wb as Workbook
FilePath = "destination folder\"
MyFile = Dir(FilePath)
Set rgCopy = ActiveSheet.Range("A1:B14")
Do While Len(MyFile) > 0
If MyFile = "Book1.xlsm" Then
Exit Sub
End If


set wb Workbooks.Open(FilePath & "\" & MyFile)
rgCopy.Copy Destination:=wb.Worksheets("A2) Monthly P&L (Source)").Range("B746")
wb.Close

MyFile = Dir

Loop

End Sub
```